# SQL Find the last time the car and parts has been used and how many work hours

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

Hi everyone i am trying to create a query that would give me last time a car were used it and also how many hours some parts are used i am trying it with SELECT MAX (DateRef) but it gives me data only for one car and i want for each car last time was used and the hours of the parts. As i am not database developer but sysadmin this looks little bit  difficult for my current knowledge. I hope someone would help me.

```
SELECT distinct  c.CarID
, DateRef
, StartHours
, a.SerialNumber
, c.CarComponentID
, c.StartHours + c.UsageHours as TTSN
from ComponentUsage c 
inner join Car A ON a.CarID = c.CarID
where c.DateRef <= '2017-12-31' and c.DateRef >= '2017-12-01' 
group by c.CarComponentID
    ,c.CarID
    , a.SerialNumber
    , starthours
    , c.dateref 
    ,c.StartHours + c.UsageHours

CarID   DateRef       StartHours SerialNumber   CarComponentID      TTSN
18  2017-12-01 03:40:00 3135.30    510-0185       71               3136.90
18  2017-12-01 03:40:00 3135.30    510-0185       72               3136.90
18  2017-12-01 03:40:00 3135.30    510-0185       73               3136.90
18  2017-12-01 03:40:00 0.00       510-0185       74               0.00
18  2017-12-01 03:40:00 3135.30    510-0185       75               3136.90
18  2017-12-01 05:56:00 3136.90    510-0185       71               3138.60
18  2017-12-01 05:56:00 3136.90    510-0185       72               3138.60
18  2017-12-01 05:56:00 3136.90    510-0185       73               3138.60
18  2017-12-01 05:56:00 0.00       510-0185       74               0.00
18  2017-12-01 05:56:00 3136.90    510-0185       75               3138.60
2   2017-12-01 06:45:00 6471.80    510-0065        1               6472.70
2   2017-12-01 06:45:00 6267.80    510-0065       15               6268.70
2   2017-12-01 06:45:00 6338.80    510-0065       29               6339.70
2   2017-12-01 06:45:00 1.20       510-0065       43               1.20
2   2017-12-01 06:45:00 6471.50    510-0065       66               6472.40
11  2017-12-01 07:10:00 4736.70    510-0196       10               4737.50
11  2017-12-01 07:10:00 4736.70    510-0196       24               4737.50
11  2017-12-01 07:10:00 4736.70    510-0196       38               4737.50
11  2017-12-01 07:10:00 0.30       510-0196       52               0.30
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach here is to, instead of joining directly the `Car` table, join to a subquery from which we can identify the latest record for each car.  The subquery below introduces a row number to each group of car records, ordered from 1 onwards, starting with the most recent record.  Then, we restrict the join by retaining only that latest car record, for each car.

```
SELECT c.CarID, DateRef, StartHours, a.SerialNumber, c.CarComponentID,
       c.StartHours + c.UsageHours AS TTSN
FROM ComponentUsage c 
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CarID ORDER BY DateRef DESC) rn
    FROM Car
) a
    ON a.CarID = c.CarID AND a.rn = 1
WHERE
    c.DateRef BETWEEN '2017-12-01' AND '2017-12-31';
```

Comment: Thanks it is almost what i need but it shows only 1 part not the 5 parts of the car that i need actually data there are more carcomponentID

Comment: Do you want the 5 most recently used components, or something else?

Comment: every car has 5 components used and tyres, brakes, etc i need to be shown  with the car number i hope you understand me

Comment: Thank you Tim unfortunately i get to many rows more than 2500 actually this thing is making me crazy i have more than 2 days spending with this report ;( so the date is not doing it write i also changed the FROM from WITH case with componentUsage because dateref is at table componentUsage

Comment: I think your database design has a problem.  Can you give me logic for how to retain only 5 car parts?  The above query would return all parts, which apparently is not what you want.

Comment: I have 2 tables Car and ComponentUsage at the table car i have data about carID, Carparking, CarModel, CarSerial, and also a table ComponentUsage that are CarID, TripID, DateRef, CarComponentID, StartHours, Description so each car has 5 parts each carComponent has unique ID.Of course i have 40 tables but this 2 i need.

Comment: Create a demo [here](http://www.rextester.com), add some data, and paste the link below.  My current query looks like it ought to work.  Without seeing your data, I'm afraid there is nothing I or anyone else can do to help you.

Answer (score 0):

> Hi everyone i am trying to create a query that would give me last time a car were used it and also how many hours some parts are used

If this is the task maybe this can help:

```
create procedure dbo.get_Cars_Last_Usage_And_Component_Time_sp
as

declare @s nvarchar(max) = ''
declare @s1 as nvarchar(max) = ''
declare @s2 as nvarchar(max) = ''

select @s1 = @s1 + '[' + cast( CarComponentID as varchar(10)) + '],'
from 
(
    select distinct CarComponentID
    from ComponentUsage
) a

if len(@s1) > 0
select @s1 = substring(@s1, 1, len(@s1) - 1)


select @s2 = @s2 + 'sum(coalesce([' + cast( CarComponentID as varchar(10)) + '], 0)) [PartNo ' + cast( CarComponentID as varchar(10)) + '],'
from 
(
    select distinct CarComponentID
    from ComponentUsage
) a

if len(@s2) > 0
select @s2 = substring(@s2, 1, len(@s2) - 1)

set @s =
'
select CarID, max(DateRef) [last time a car were used], ' + @s2 + '
from
(
    select *
    from ComponentUsage
) AS SourceTable
pivot
(
    sum(TTSN)
    FOR CarComponentID in(' + @s1 + ')
) AS PivotTable
group by CarID
'

exec sp_executesql @s
```

will give you output like this:

[image]